# Feeding multiple values in a loop to an array with VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

**Scenario:** I am reading through folders and subfolders of a directory, if the found file is an ".xls" it opens. I then run another condition that, if true, will try to pass some values to the array.

**Objective:** I am defining my array without dimensions, because I don't know how many files will feed into it. For each file that fulfills the conditions, I am trying to get 3 values (name, path, date) and add to the array. Each file would be added to a new row of the array.

**Ex. of array:**

If 3 files fulfill the condition...

```
name1    path1    date1
name2    path2    date2
name3    path3    date3
```

**Issue:** when I run, I get a subscript out of range error when I try to pass the values to the array. How can I fix that?

**Code1:** This starts the loop through folders

```
Public Sub getInputFileInfo()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    ' User selects where to search for files:
    HostFolder = GetFolder()

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

End Sub
```

**Code2:** This gets the data:

```
Public Sub DoFolder(Folder)

    Dim strFilename As String, filePath As String
    Dim dateC As Date
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim outputarray() As Variant
    Dim ii As Long, lRow As Long, lCol As Long, lRow2 As Long
    Dim w2, w As Workbook
    Set w = ThisWorkbook

    ii = 1

    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next SubFolder
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        'Set w2 = File

        filePath = File.Path
        strFilename = File.Name
        dateC = File.dateCreated
        If InStr(LCase(File.Path), LCase("xls")) <> 0 Then
            Set w2 = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
            For lRow2 = 1 To w2.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If w2.Sheets(1).Range("A" & lRow2).Value = "Test Name" Then
                    outputarray(0, ii) = strFilename ' THE ERROR STARTS HERE
                    outputarray(1, ii) = filePath
                    outputarray(2, ii) = dateC
                    ii = ii + 1
                End If
            Next lRow2
            w2.Close False
        End If
        Set oFS = Nothing
    Next File

    For lRow = 1 To UBound(outputarray, 1)
        For lCol = 1 To UBound(outputarray, 2)
            w.Sheets("ControlSheet").Cells(lRow, lCol).Value = outputarray(lRow, lCol).Value
        Next lCol
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use [ReDim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) but I would probably prefer another data structure like a dictionary or collection.

Comment: Or a collection of dictionaries! You have the three keys you want to associate values for each time. With the array idea I would have had the increment in the rows argument and held the columns constant with 0,1,2. Also, oversize at start and redim at end using a counter variable.

Comment: @Storax How can I do that?

Comment: How can you do what? Using Redim is described in the link I provided.

Comment: @Storax Sorry, I should have specified better. How could I use a dictionary in this case? Also, I am now trying redim, but the array dimensions are getting out of control for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with these steps:

1) temporarily size the array to the maximum number of files

2) keep track of found files

3) finally resize array to actual number of found files

As follows (I only show relevant snippet):

```
ii = -1 '<<< initialize the counter fo found files to -1: it's more convenient for its subsequent updating and usage
ReDim outputarray(0 To 2, 0 To Folder.Files.Count) As Variant ' <<< temporarily size the array to the maximum number of files

For Each File In Folder.Files
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Set w2 = File

    filePath = File.Path
    strFilename = File.Name
    dateC = File.dateCreated
    If InStr(LCase(File.Path), LCase("xls")) <> 0 Then
        Set w2 = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
        For lRow2 = 1 To w2.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If w2.Sheets(1).Range("A" & lRow2).Value = "Test Name" Then
                ii = ii + 1 '<<< update the number of found files
                outputarray(0, ii) = strFilename
                outputarray(1, ii) = filePath
                outputarray(2, ii) = dateC
            End If
        Next lRow2
        w2.Close False
    End If
    Set oFS = Nothing
Next File

ReDim Preserve outputarray(0 To 2, 0 To ii) As Variant '<<< finally resize array to actual number of found files
```

---

> edit

BTW you can avoid the double nested writing loops and use a one shot statement:

```
w.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(outputarray, 1) + 1, UBound(outputarray, 2) + 1).Value = outputarray
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a dictionary and a "class" like in the following example.
The class fInfo looks like that

```
Option Explicit

Public fileName As String
Public filepath As String
Public fileDateCreated As Date
```

Then you could test it like that

```
Sub AnExample()

Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim fInfo As fileInfo

Dim filepath As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim dateC As Date
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 2
        filepath = "Path\" & i
        strFilename = "Name" & i
        dateC = Now + 1

        Set fInfo = New fileInfo
        With fInfo
            .filepath = filepath
            .fileName = strFilename
            .fileDateCreated = dateC
        End With
        dict.Add i, fInfo
    Next i

    For i = 1 To dict.Count
        With dict.Item(i)
            Debug.Print .filepath, .fileName, .fileDateCreated
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

In your code maybe like that

```
    For lRow2 = 1 To w2.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If w2.Sheets(1).Range("A" & lRow2).Value = "Test Name" Then
            Set fInfo = New fileInfo
            With fInfo
                .filepath = filepath
                .fileName = strFilename
                .fileDateCreated = dateC
            End With
            dict.Add ii, fInfo
'            outputarray(0, ii) = strFilename    ' THE ERROR STARTS HERE
'            outputarray(1, ii) = filepath
'            outputarray(2, ii) = dateC
'            ii = ii + 1
        End If
    Next lRow2
```